# Migrating data from apache gridgain to ignite

Tags: migration, ignite, gridgain

We currently use Gridgain Community edition and are looking to move into Apache Ignite.
Is there a way to migrate persisted data into a new Ignite cluster from the grid gain cluster without developing a custom copy tool?

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind that you use latest versions of GridGain CE and Ignite, as I know, there would be no problems, i'm using both in development. Are you using Ignite native persistence or third-party persistence? But still best case would be transfer setttings and restart cluster, so you would evade possible problems with baseline topology, as example.